# How to connect my POS which is build in Visual basic to an EFTPOS machine to accept card payments

Tags: visual-studio, payment-gateway, payment-processing, point-of-sale

I have developed a Point of Sale software and need assistance in connecting it to an EFTPOS (Electronic Funds Transfer at Point of Sale) card reader machine, specifically the Ingenico Move5000 model. This connection is required to facilitate credit and debit card payments.

The software is built using Visual Basic .NET version 3.5. Any assistance with this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Need the SDK for the connection and sample codes

Answer (score 0):

AjKu, This post is pretty old but thought I would answer anyway. I’m assuming that you are doing some kind of direct connection to the device over USB? For a direct connected device you would normally get the SDK from your payment processor as they will likely have special software running on that device. You may also want to look at different devices that do not have a direct connection, but rather connect through an online API and can be activated with a simple REST API call. For our product, we work with a payment processor named USIO and they have a few different terminals that are all “smart” ones. They run Android, cost less than $300 and just connect to Wifi or ethernet. When you want to take a payment you just call USIO’s API and say which terminal you want to light up and the amount and it will activate the terminal and take the payment. Also to note, they way they work does NOT require any firewall exceptions or special routing.